# How to relate two tables of data

Tags: postgresql, database-design

[image]

Hello, I have this simple diagram showing two tables, event table and guest table.

I created an event which has id of 1 and there are 3 guests for event id of 1. If I want to reuse the same guests for event id 2 and 3, how do I relate them using a foreign key? What if I want to remove Joe from the event 2, how do I do it so that it won't delete Joe from the table because Joe is needed for event 1? I am confused and I don't know if my question is clear enough. Do I need to add some columns to help this out?

Comment: In shown schema you will have more than one record for each guest - one record for each event. Removing the record with name=Joe and event=2 will not remove the record with name=Joe and event=1. And you can NOT "reuse" records.

Comment: One user matched many events. One event matched many users. The relation is M:N. It needs 3 tables - users (id, name, etc.), events (id, name, etc.), and users_events (isers_id, events_id). The last table has 2 FKs - to each another table.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your suggestion could be the solution for me and I will try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uses a third table that will link the Event table to the Guest table :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Steph74. I will try this out tonight and mark this as the solution.